Prevent some keys from being picked up by Weblate as strings that need translation
In the JSON file that I read into Weblate, I have a key that is not needed for translation but contains context to where this translation can be used. It's not ideal, but it's how it is now.
Is there a way to tell Weblate that certain keys should not appear in the translation GUI for the translators?

The only way to achieve this currently in Weblate is implementing native support for such files.

Thanks, I will look into this. If you happen to know where to start to look I'd appreciate the hint :)

The very basic info is available at https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/formats.html#supporting-other-formats
